# Execute Multiple Statements/Lines simultaneously in PHP

Tags: php, speech-recognition, speech, google-speech-to-text-api

I am sure there are lots of people who have the same queries, I want to execute 2 lines same time. not the 2 scripts same time using PHP coding. for example, I have a file that I have to send to google API for the speech recognition, and at the same time I want to execute another line and I don't want my program to wait for the API to give a response and then execute.

```
$recording_file = '/opt/sounds/recoginze.wav';
exec("gcloud ml speech recognize $recording_file --language-code='en-US'",$output,$retval);
$transcript = $output['6'];
```

Normally above statement will take 3 to 4 seconds to respond, I want the other line to execute simultaneously like play recording.

```
$play_sound = playSound($recording_file);
```

Let me know your inputs and ideas.

Note: I am no programmer in PHP, I am just a sysadmin, who trying to learn PHP.

Answer (score 0):

When you have a question about PHP, the first thing to do is to read the relevant PHP documentation.

You are using `exec()`. It is possible to make an `exec()` call to run without waiting for the result. See the first note in the [PHP documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php).

Below that note, you will also find a code example by *Arno van den Brink* that might do what you want.

Comment: Thank you for the response, if I run the execinbackground as per Arno van den, I won't get the result of the executed commands. I tried and it doesn't work the way I expected.